# Generic methods cast this to T

Tags: c#, generics

I have this class

```
class A
{
    public string OnlyOnA { get; private set; }

    public virtual void Accept<T>(ITaker<T> ia) where T : A
    {
        ia.Take((T)this);
    }
}
```

and this interface

```
interface ITaker<T> where T : A
{
    void Take(T a);
}
```

with this I can subclass A like following

```
class B : A
{
    public string OnlyOnB { get; private set; }    
}
```

and implement the interface

```
class BTaker : ITaker<B>
{
    public void Take(B b)
    {
        var v = b.OnlyOnB;
    }
}
```

I get the flexibilty in the Taker class to get the correct type of A and subtypes of A.
but I still need to the cast in A where I have to do (T)this;

how can I avoid the cast?

many thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you are trying to do is unsafe since you can do:

```
new A().Accept(new BTaker());
```

To make this safe you could create a new interface to specify the type of `T` which can be accepted e.g.

```
interface IAccept<T> where T : A
{
    void Accept(ITaker<T> taker);
}

class A : IAccept<A>
{
    public string OnlyOnA { get; private set; }

    public virtual void Accept(ITaker<A> ia)
    {
        ia.Take(this);
    }
}
```